# Can't close in a safe way a stream video QThread in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, video-streaming, qthread, alliedvision

I am writing a program in pyqt that needs to display a real-time video stream acquired via an Allied Vision camera (Alvium G1-500m).
In the code I have made a mainthread that manages the gui and launches the various routines via QThread.
The QThread that launches the stream works and returns the image correctly, the problem occurs at the moment when I want to close the program.
The moment the program is closed, the closure is done in a forced manner, it crashes since the QThread of the stream is not killed in a safe manner.
Now it will be logical to say " Close the QThread in a safe way," here, I can't find the right way.
This code works, the QThread is only killed in a safe manner when the enter key is pressed from the terminal, but I need the use of a signal or something similar to do it automatically

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from vmbpy import *
import sys


class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    stop_stream_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, size_image: list, offset_image: list, exposure: int):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.cam = None
        self.allocation_mode = AllocationMode.AnnounceFrame
        self.opencv_display_format = PixelFormat.Mono8
        self.exposure = exposure
        self.widthFrameCamera = size_image[0]
        self.heightFrameCamera = size_image[1]
        self.offsetXCamera = offset_image[0]
        self.offsetYCamera = offset_image[1]
        self.mutex = True

    def run(self) -> None:
        with VmbSystem.get_instance() as vmb:
            cams = vmb.get_all_cameras()
            with cams[0] as cam:
                self.cam = cam

                self.setup_camera(cam)
                try:

                    # Start Streaming with a custom a buffer of 10 Frames (defaults to 5)
                    cam.start_streaming(handler=self.frame_handler,
                                        buffer_count=10,
                                        allocation_mode=self.allocation_mode)
                    input() # That function is waiting for enter button in the command line

                finally: # once the enter key has been pressed the finally is executed
                    cam.stop_streaming()


    def setup_camera(self, cam: Camera):
        #Some code

    def setup_pixel_format(self, ):
        #Some code

    def frame_handler(self, cam: Camera, stream: Stream, frame: Frame):
        # print('{} acquired {}'.format(cam, frame), flush=True)
        image = frame.as_opencv_image()
        bytes_per_frame = self.widthFrameCamera
        qt_format = QtGui.QImage(image,
                                 self.widthFrameCamera,
                                 self.heightFrameCamera,
                                 bytes_per_frame,
                                 QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        
        self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(qt_format) #Image emitted to GUI
        self.cam.queue_frame(frame)
```

That's my main window, the code currently being closed does not handle the safe closure of the stream

```
import time

import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QShortcut, QLabel, QFrame
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QKeySequence, QPen, QPainter, QCloseEvent, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PIL import Image
import shutil
from frontend.gui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
import cameraThread
import azureThread
import os
import json


class OcrWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        ##Read config file where are stored Azure API KEY and some info about the camera
        ##TODO: think about what kind of info about the camera put in this file
        file_config = self.readConfigFile()
        size_image = file_config['sizeImage']
        offset_image = file_config['offsetImage']
        exposure = file_config['exposure']
        azureconfig = file_config['azure']

        ##Stream box
        streamBox = QVBoxLayout()
        streamBox.addWidget(self.imageStream)
        self.imageTemp = None

        self.streamThread = cameraThread.VideoThread(size_image,offset_image,exposure)
        self.streamThread.start()


    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def renderStreamImage(self, img):
        new_image = QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        painterInstance = QPainter(new_image)
        penRectangle = QPen(Qt.red)
        penRectangle.setWidth(3)
        painterInstance.setPen(penRectangle)
        painterInstance.drawRect(182.5, 247.5, 605, 205)
        self.imageStream.setPixmap(new_image)
        self.imageTemp = new_image


    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the thread to stop gracefully
        sys.exit(app.exec())  # Accept the close event

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = OcrWindow()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The first thing I did was try to add a flag that is set to False when the stream is to be closed. This resolution does not work since the stream still does not terminate.

```
class VideoThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, size_image: list, offset_image: list, exposure: int):
        QThread.__init__(self)

        self.mutex = True

    def run(self) -> None:
        with VmbSystem.get_instance() as vmb:
            cams = vmb.get_all_cameras()
            with cams[0] as cam:
                self.cam = cam

                self.setup_camera(cam)
                try:

                    # Start Streaming with a custom a buffer of 10 Frames (defaults to 5)
                    cam.start_streaming(handler=self.frame_handler,
                                        buffer_count=10,
                                        allocation_mode=self.allocation_mode)

                    #Deleted Input() function
                    while self.mutex:  ## < --
                         pass
                     
                finally: # once the enter key has been pressed the finally is executed
                    cam.stop_streaming()


    def setup_camera(self, cam: Camera):
        #Some code

    def setup_pixel_format(self, ):
        #Some code

    def frame_handler(self, cam: Camera, stream: Stream, frame: Frame):
        #Some code

    def abort(self, return_code: int = 1): ## <--
        self.mutex = False



class OcrWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #Same code


    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        self.streamThread.abort()  ## <--
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the thread to stop gracefully
        sys.exit(app.exec())  # Accept the close event
```

The second option I used was to use a pyqtSignal() signal so as to pass in a thread safe way the notification of an event. In this way, closing in safe mode works, but it creates another basic problem, which is a drastic drop in FPS and a flickering of the camera stream while using it

```
class VideoThread(QThread):
    stop_stream_signal = pyqtSignal()  ## <-
    def __init__(self, size_image: list, offset_image: list, exposure: int):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self) -> None:
        with VmbSystem.get_instance() as vmb:
            cams = vmb.get_all_cameras()
            with cams[0] as cam:
                self.cam = cam

                self.setup_camera(cam)
                try:

                    # Start Streaming with a custom a buffer of 10 Frames (defaults to 5)
                    cam.start_streaming(handler=self.frame_handler,
                                        buffer_count=10,
                                        allocation_mode=self.allocation_mode)

                   self.stop_stream_signal.connect(self.stop_stream) ## <-

                    while self.isRunning(): #<--
                         pass
                     
                finally: # once the enter key has been pressed the finally is executed
                    cam.stop_streaming()

    def stop_stream(self):  ## <--
        self.quit()

    def setup_camera(self, cam: Camera):
        #Some code

    def setup_pixel_format(self, ):
        #Some code

    def frame_handler(self, cam: Camera, stream: Stream, frame: Frame):
        #Some code




class OcrWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #Same code


    def closeEvent(self, event: QCloseEvent):
        self.streamThread.stop_stream_signal.emit() ## <--

        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the thread to stop gracefully
        sys.exit(app.exec())  # Accept the close event
```

Could you also explain why the input function does not create these problems?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just call `self.streamThread.cam.stop_streaming()`?